# How to minimize or maximize a function over a finite field in WolframAlpha?

Tags: optimization, computational-mathematics, wolfram-alpha

Is it possible to ask WolframAlpha to minimize or maximize a function with variables in a finite field?

Let's take a stupid example: how do I ask WolframAlpha to maximize $x_1+x_2$ with $x_1, x_2\in\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Thanks!

Edit: let's consider, in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the order $[0]<[1]$.

Comment: Finite fields have no order! There is no meaning in "maximizing" or "minimizing" over a finite field.

Comment: Maximizing something implies that you have some ordering on the finite field. However, as finite fields have positive characteristic, they are not ordered fields. I'm not aware of any nice ordering on a finite field, as none respect the field structure itself.

Comment: @Poecilia $ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $ is a set of equivalence classes modulo 2. If I instead wrote $ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = \{[1000], [1]\} $, where $ [a] $ denotes the equivalence class modulo 2, which element would you now choose as the maximum?

Comment: For $\Bbb{F}_2$ we can maximize, taking the order of the standard representatives in the integers. But take $\Bbb{F}_4$. This is not $\Bbb{Z}/4$. Try to compare the elements with respect to $\le$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks, this is what I meant. I want to maximize taking the order of the standard representatives in the integers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The ordering you propose is not well defined. Letting $ [n] $ denote the mod 2 congruence class of the integer $ n $, we have in this ordering, $ [0] < [1] < [1000] $, but $ [1000] = [0] $, so $ [0] < [0] $.
Edit: I just saw that you made sure the representative chosen was standard in this ordering, so the above argument can be disregarded.

Comment: @user571438 I think that he meant [0]<[1].